# Messages in the minibuffer (or echo area) waiting for user RETURN

Tags: message

What ways can I display a message in the minibuffer (or echo area) waiting for the user RETURN.

I mean I want to display a message and be sure that a script waits for the user to read it.

I usually use `(read-string)` function:

```
Do something...
(read-string "Description or Warning") ;; Waiting for user RETURN
Do something else...
```

Is there a more orthodox way to do it?

**Edit.** The thing is, I don't really need to read anything from the minibuffer: I just want to display a message and be sure that the user carefully read it. I need the user to confirm the reading by typing `RETUN`.

Comment: See the minibuffer chapter in the Elisp manual: `C-h i g(elisp)Minibuffers`. The most general method is `read-from-minibuffer` but there are several more specialized methods (e.g. `completing-read` if you want to provide completion). And `read-string` is in there too.

Comment: What @NickD said, exactly.

Comment: I edited my question trying to clarifying the point.

Comment: Does `read-string` work for this? If so, just use it and don't worry about orthodoxy (IMO, it's perfectly orthodox, but that's beside the point). If not, what more do you need?

Comment: @NickD `read-string` does the job. I was just looking for something "cleaner." I was worried about using a function meant for other purposes.

Comment: It's desgined to read a string (including an empty string) from the minibuffer, it is simpler than the underlying `read-from-minibuffer` (or at least it is simpler to type), all arguments (except for the prompt) are optional and are defaulted sensibly: sounds perfect to me, unless you find something even simpler in the section I pointed out.